# how to write elasticsearch script_score in java api

Tags: api, elasticsearch, java

I find a function in ElasticSearch like

```
GET /_search
{
  "function_score": {
    "functions": [
      { ...location clause... }, 
      { ...price clause... }, 
      {
        "script_score": {
          "params": { 
            "threshold": 80,
            "discount": 0.1,
            "target": 10
          },
          "script": "price  = doc['price'].value; margin = doc['margin'].value;
          if (price < threshold) { return price * margin / target };
          return price * (1 - discount) * margin / target;" 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- I use `ScoreFunctionBuilder` to achive the "location caluse" and
  "price caluse" ,but I do not know how to write `"script_score"` and `"script"` by java api
- The ES version in my project is 2.2.0 and I use the
  java api to achieve this function
- But I can not find the API like 
  `ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder. scriptFunction(String script,
  Map<String, Object> params)` how can I do？  Thx :)
- Finally I figure out how to write it by using JD-JUI to check the "elasticsearch.jar" file.

EX:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("num1", 10);
    params.put("num2", 4);

    String inlineScript = "doc['score'].value * num1 * num2";

    Script script = new Script(script, ScriptType.INLINE, "groovy", params);

    ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder scriptBuilder = ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction(ss);
```

that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can implement scrip_ score function in java

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();                   
params.put("paramName1", "paramVal1")
params.put("paramName2", "paramVal2");

String script = "price  = doc['price'].value; margin = doc['margin'].value;
      if (price < threshold) { return price * margin / target };
      return price * (1 - discount) * margin / target;"
XContentBuilder builder = 
                    new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder()
                    .script(script)
                    .lang("groovy")
                    .params(params)
                    .toXContent(XContentBuilder, params);
```

Comment: Please add some details on why is this an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, but the `new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder()` does not work in my project. The API must be `new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder(Script) ` , it can not be write like your's ,only can write like 
                `new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder(script).toXContent(builder, params)`  Am I use the wrong API? My english is poor ,sorry :(

Comment: I am not able to understand. Why doesn't new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder() work ? There is no other constructor. Also, you can always do new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder().scrip(SCRIPT).toXContent(builder, params)

Comment: Because the public method of new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder() must have args "Script" like new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder(script),now I am working on how to write new ScriptScoreFunctionBuilder().scrip(SCRIPT).toXContent(builder, params)

Comment: The class already has a public method which takes script as an argument. I have updated my answer to showcase.

Comment: glad it helped you :)